# Filter Stream to List

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have the following stream builder:

```
streamCard() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: cardsRef
            .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
            .limit(10)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return circularProgress();
          }
          List<CustomCard> cards = [];
          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
            cards.add(CustomCard.fromDocument(doc));
          });
...
return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: cards,
            );
```

I need to filter certain cards from being added to the stream/displayed when:

- I'm the owner of the card ('ownerId' == currentUserId)
- I've liked the card ('liked.' contains = currentUserId)

*OwnerId is a field inside each document and Liked is an array with Id's who have liked it.*

I've tried to remove the cards from being added to the cards List<> with .where and .contains, but couldn't properly 'discard' them. I was thinking another option could be to modify the Stack directly, in

```
children: cards
```

with cards.removeWhere/.skip, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the bloc pattern, business logic should happen in your bloc class. Which mean that you should do all the sorting or filtering in the bloc. When you add a new object into sink, the streambuilder will rebuild.

```
class BlaBloc {
final BehaviorSubject<List<String>> _results =
      BehaviorSubject<List<String>>();

getResults() {
    List<String> yourresults = yourapi.getResults();
    _results.sink.add(yourresults);
};

getResultsLikedByMe() {
    List<String> yourresults = yourapi.getResultsLikedByMe();
    _results.sink.add(yourresults);
}

getResultsOwnerIsMe() {
    List<String> yourresults = yourapi.getResultsOwnerIsMe();
    _results.sink.add(yourresults);
}

BehaviorSubject<List<String>> get results => _results;
}

final blaBloc = BlaBloc();
```

When you build your streambuilder, point to your Bloc, for example as below:

```
body: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
stream: blaBloc.results,
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<RecipesResponse> snapshot) {
// build your list here...
}
)
```

To understand more about Bloc pattern, this is a very useful tutorial you could follow here: [RxDart Bloc Pattern](https://medium.com/flutter-community/why-use-rxdart-and-how-we-can-use-with-bloc-pattern-in-flutter-a64ca2c7c52d)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how would I combine the results to filter out those exceptions? Like getResults (whole list), minus getResultsLikedByMe and getResultsOwnerIsMe? Thanks!

Comment: 1. create an API that only returns those values, for instance, getResultOwnerIsNotMeAndNotLikedByMe, this should be done at the API level.

2. get the list from getResults and add the filtered/mapped value to the sink. [dart list foreach] (https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2)